# Why do we need to delay the reading of bytes in UART communication?

Tags: embedded, system, uart

We have a strange problem and since I'm not an experienced embedded systems developer I can't get my head around this problem.

We use two MCU's with different clock speeds. We have an UART connection between them. We used a baudrate of 115200 and we had little but some errors. We switched to 9600 and we get more errors (which is strange imho).

We found out that communication from MCUfast -> MCUslow is going right all the time. But communication from MCUslow -> MCUfast is having errors.

Now comes our solution which is working but I don't know why:

**We have built in a delay of 1ms in the MCUfast interrupt handler after reading each byte. Now we don't have any errors anymore.**

Since using a delay in a while loop isn't that good of a plan I'm trying to find out what causes this behaviour to figure out a fix that is acceptable.

Did anybody encounter such a problem before and could point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance

**Edit**

```
void D10::OnUsartInterrupt(void* Context)
{
    D10* Con = (D10*)Context;

    while ((uint32_t)Con->DataSerial->GetStatus() & (uint32_t)UsartStatus::RXReady)
    {
        Con->Data[Con->Index++] = Con->DataSerial->Receive();
        Con->MessageReady = true;
        PowerManager::DelayMs(1);   
    }   
}
```

Comment: Seems like you aren't waiting for some flag  you should be waiting on. Or baudrate prescaling is inaccurate. Etc Etc. This is almost certainly a software bug, so without the actual code any answer will just be speculation.

Comment: A delay in a while loop is not specifically an issue - a delay in an interrupt handler _is_ and even a while-loop in an interrupt handler may be.  For an answer we need to see your interrupt handler and other associated UART code (initialisation etc) and you need to specify the precise  MCU part number.  Currently you are asking us to look through the keyhole of your front door and asking the us to tell you the colour of eh wallpaper in the back bedroom!

Comment: Calculate from the UART prescalers what the **actual baud rate** you use on both ends is and how much it differs between MCUs

Comment: You definitely need to wait for a flag which shows that a byte has arrived. The time you built in matches quite good the time needed to transmit a byte at 9600 baud.

Comment: I added the interrupt handler code. We use a while loop inside of the handler to read out the data. When we delay the while loop we encounter very little data corruption. Without it we get corruption in 10% of the data.

Comment: Well this is just some C++ goo we can't interpret without the class definitions available. Disassemble this to see what machine code you actually got - is the code actually clearing the flags? It also seems very likely that you have race condition bugs in addition to your UART problems. Any why do you use `void*` if you insist on using C++?

Comment: On your last question I don't have an answer. I've inherited this code from another programmer. I'll try to dive deeper into the UART protocol since I don't really have a clue where to start.

Comment: I assume it is bytes that your ISR place in Con->Data at index Con->Index, right? How does the consumer of Con->Data look like, could there be a race updating Con->Index both from thread and ISR?